# Python3 reading text file with 6 values divided by a comma in each line and listing line

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose i have a file.txt, in each line of it 6 value divided by a comma.
a,b,c,d,e,f

How can I list each line in the form of [a,b,c,d,e,f]?

Comment: use ```.split()```, google it (this is supposing you know how to open text files and read them, for that google: ```read() ```)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest using `.split()`, as it can split it like this:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
f.read()
spited = f.split(",")
print(spited)
```

Which prints the numbers/letters as a list.

If you have any questions on why/how this works, just ask!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your tips, ive finally managed to do what i wanted with this piece of code:

```
 with open(l, "r") as f:
   for line in f:
    inner_list = [elt.strip() for elt in line.split(',')]
```